# Python: Query data from Mysql in UTF-8

Tags: python, mysql

I created my database with MySql and set collation as utf8_unicode_ci.
And I query data in python program as this code

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="password",db="database",charset="utf8",use_unicode=True)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("select `name` from car_park where p_id=1" )
rows=cur.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

But the out put is u'\u0e40\u0e14\u0e2d\u0e30\u0e21\u0e2d\u0e25\u0e4c'.
Actually the data source in database is Thai language. Anyone else have been query data from database in Thai language or another UTF-8 by python please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`rows` seems to be a list and you should iterate over it.

```
for row in rows:
    print row
```

Printing a unicode object shouldn't make mistakes.

Comment: @decltype_auto Well, As far as I tried, `print u'\u0e40\u0e14\u0e2d\u0e30\u0e21\u0e2d\u0e25\u0e4c'` always gives a Thai string. Thus I think Chin may have done `print rows` which prints `[u'\u0e40\u0e14\u0e2d\u0e30\u0e21\u0e2d\u0e25\u0e4c']`

Comment: @decltype_auto on the contrary. Compare `print(u'\u0e40\u0e14\u0e2d\u0e30\u0e21\u0e2d\u0e25\u0e4c')` with `print([u'\u0e40\u0e14\u0e2d\u0e30\u0e21\u0e2d\u0e25\u0e4c'])`; the first shows the rendered text, the second shows the escape codes; because when you print a list, each element is shown with `repr()`.